# Ruby on Rails: number_field/text_field not saving values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, forms

I'm having a small issue with saving form values. I made a form for updating some database values, and I've ran into a peculiar problem.

I created 3 variables for several items, here are the first 3 from the form.

follow_up_logs/edit.html.erb

```
<div id="followuplog_attribute_update">
    <p>
        Baseline Target: 
        <%= f.number_field :baseline_target %>
    </p>
    <p>
        Baseline Completed:
        <%= f.number_field :baseline_completed %>
    </p>
    <p>
        Baseline Reasons:
        <%= f.text_field :baseline_completed %>
    </p>            
</div>
```

And, to show you the pattern, here are the second three:

```
<div id="followuplog_attribute_update">
    <p>
        3 Week Target: 
        <%= f.number_field :week3_target %>
    </p>
    <p>
        3 Week Completed:
        <%= f.number_field :week3_completed %>
    </p>
    <p>
        3 Week Reasons:
        <%= f.text_field :week3_completed %>
    </p>            
</div>
```

Here is how I created them:

add_column :follow_up_logs, :baseline_target, :integer
  add_column :follow_up_logs, :baseline_completed, :integer
  add_column :follow_up_logs, :baseline_reasons, :string

add_column :follow_up_logs, :week3_target, :integer
  add_column :follow_up_logs, :week3_completed, :integer
  add_column :follow_up_logs, :week3_reasons, :string

**The problem is**, only the target variable saves. All the rest don't save to the database. So when I submit the form, for some odd reason, :baseline_target and :week3_target both save to the database, however nothing else does. (Well, actually the completed variables save as 0 and the reasons variables are left as nil)

Here are my controller actions:

follow_up_logs_controller.rb

```
  def new
    @follow_up_log = FollowUpLog.new
  end

  def create
    @follow_up_log = FollowUpLog.new(params[:follow_up_log])

    if @follow_up_log.save
        redirect_to @follow_up_log
    else
        render 'new'
    end
  end

  def update
    @follow_up_log = FollowUpLog.find(params[:id])
    if @follow_up_log.update_attributes(params[:follow_up_log])
      flash[:success] = "Log Updated"
      redirect_to @follow_up_log
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @follow_up_log = FollowUpLog.find(params[:id])
  end
```

I haven't been able to figure out what's going on, any help would be greatly appreciated. I feel like it must be something small I keep missing =(

edit. spelling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are **repeating** the attribute `:baseline_completed`.

```
<p>
    Baseline Completed:
    <%= f.number_field :baseline_completed %>
</p>
<p>
    Baseline Reasons:
    <%= f.text_field :baseline_completed %>  ## <== should be :baseline_reasons
</p>
```

**Same goes for other form with `:week3_completed`**

That's why when you submit the form the text_field value overrides the number_field value. And   your completed variables save as 0 and the reasons variables are left as `nil`.